# Does a Windows 10 repair flash drive need to be one used for installation?

Tags: windows-10, usb-flash-drive, repair

I want to make a backup of the USB flash drive which I recently used to install Windows 10, on a second flash drive. For the backup flash drive, is it best to create a new one using the media creation tool, or to clone the flash drive which I used for the installation? Or does it not matter?

In other words, when using the flash drive to repair Windows, does it need to be the actual drive I used to install Windows?

Maybe a silly question, but hey...

Comment: The Media Creation Tool should pick out the version you are using and repair it. So it should not matter.

Comment: Thanks, John. I used the Media Creation Tool to create the original installation drive with only the 32 bit option (my PC is 32 bit). So if I now created a second 32 bit only installation flash drive using the MCT, I assume that should okay as a repair drive, if the first flash drive happened to fail.

Comment: Yes, it should be fine as the MCL will pick out the correct version to install.

Comment: 32-bit Windows 10? How well does that work? On a 32-bit PC, I was found any version of Windows after XP too slow to be usable, and have switched to Linux, for that reason.

Comment: Yes, 32-bit is slow. But MCL will still work for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Media Creation Tool (Media Creation Link) as it picks out the version of software you have.

You can clone your installation flash drive if you wish.

The Media Creation Tool is the most general and will always be up to date.

I have used this to recover a PC back to Windows 10 from Windows 11 Insider and also to repair a PC.

> In other words, when using the flash drive to repair Windows, does it
> need to be the actual drive I used to install Windows?

It does not need to be the actual drive you used to install Windows. The Media Creation Link works well and is more general.

Comment: Thank you. I was a bit confused by the answers because in the event of needing to repair windows, without access to another computer, only the installation flash drive would be available, and the MCT wouldn't be needed. So my question was just about whether the flash drive used for the installation would be needed for the repair, or would any another flash drive not used for installation be okay (a second copy of the installation flash drive).

Comment: I think you've kindly answered that already, but I thought I'd better explain a bit more, in case my question hadn't been clear.

Comment: The Media Creation LInk works just fine to either rebuild or repair a PC. I have done both. You can put that on a flash drive or use your original flash drive. The Medis Creation Link is better as it is always updated. I amended my answer as well